# Angular - Module has no exported member 'OpaqueToken' Error

Tags: angular

[image]

How should I resolve this error:

> ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/ng2.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/sandr/Desktop/wzór — kopia/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'

It's happened when I try to join (`@import`) anything with `@ngrx`.

Comment: You're using a version of ngrx that is not compatible with the version of Angular that you're using.

Comment: this can be fixed by installing latest version of ngrx, `npm install ngrx@latest --save`, because yes in package.json the version of ngrx you have been used, its not compatible with version of angular.

Comment: @Vinod you saved my life - thank you